# Filter polymorphic relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have such entities as: user, contact, activity, touch.

One user has many contacts. One contact has many activities. Activity is polymorphic and may be a touch or something else. Touch has a type (email/visit/call).

I need to count how many contacts a user has, which have activities which are touches with visit type.

So this is how to count number of contacts which have activities no matter what type:

```
$this->model->find($id)->contacts()->whereHas('activities')->count();
```

But how to take into account only activities which are touches with type visit?

```
$this->model->find($id)->contacts()->whereHas('activities', function($query) {
   $query->whereType('App\EloquentModels\Touch') // And touch must have type = visit
)->count();
```

**update**

Well, seems like I achivied some result with query builder. One note: an activity table also polymorphic for contacts because it might be as well belong to other entities. Shouldn't be a big difference. What I want to be pretty written without joins is:

```
\DB::table('users')->join('contacts', 'contacts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                           ->join('activities', 'activitable_id', '=', 'contacts.id')
                           ->join('touches', 'touches.id', '=', 'activities.child_id')
                           ->where('activities.activitable_type', '=', 'CRM\EloquentModels\Contact')
                           ->where('activities.child_type', '=', 'CRM\EloquentModels\Touch')
                           ->where('touches.type', '=', 'visit')
                           ->distinct()
                           ->count('contacts.id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the filter part, if you get() the query, then you will retrieve a Collection, then you can run a filter for that collection to get only what you seek.

```
   $this->model
        ->find($id)
        ->contacts()
        ->whereHas('activities',  function($query) {
            $query->whereType('App\EloquentMode\Touch')
                ->get()
                ->filter(function($touch){
                    if($touch->type == 'visit') return $touch;
                });
            })
       ->count();
```